# Can not create a local and remote branch (tracking) at the same time

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-remote

From [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches):

> you can set up other tracking branches if you wish — ones that don’t
>   track branches on origin and don’t track the master branch. The simple
>   case is the example you just saw, running git checkout -b [branch]
>   [remotename]/[branch]
>
> $ git checkout --track origin/serverfix   Branch serverfix set up to
>   track remote branch refs/remotes/origin/serverfix.   Switched to a new
>   branch "serverfix"
>
> $ git checkout -b sf origin/serverfix   Branch sf set up to track
>   remote branch refs/remotes/origin/serverfix.   Switched to a new
>   branch "sf"

My understanding is that this presents a way to create a local branch and an upstream branch.

But when I do:

`git checkout -b iss53 origin/iss53` I get:
`fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'iss53' at the same time.`

And when I do:
`git checkout --track origin/iss53`  I get:

> fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'iss53' at the same
>   time. Did you intend to checkout 'origin/iss53' which can not be
>   resolved as commit?

Why?

Answer (score 7):

```
Cannot update paths and switch to branch
```

As I mention in "[Get new upstream branch with git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731197/6309)", you can try:

```
# let's create a new local branch first
git checkout -b iss53
# then reset its starting point
git reset --hard origin/iss53
```

Make sure that the [remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch/1070851#1070851) `origin/iss53` does exist first (after a `git fetch origin`)

`origin/iss53` means there was a `iss53` on the [upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) remote repo referenced by `origin`.

If there was not such a branch, then you only create a local branch `iss53`, and push it like so:

```
git push -u origin iss53
```

That would establish an association between the local branch `iss53` and the remote tracking branch `origin/iss53` (tracking the newly created branch `iss53` on `origin`, created by the push).

See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)" for more on that initial push.

Comment: But how do I create `origin/iss53` in the first place?

Comment: The hint to get from "upstream" rather than "origin" in the referenced answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730551/get-new-upstream-branch-with-git/15731197#15731197) was what I was missing.

Comment: when I go git reset --hard upstream/origin I get:

    fatal: ambiguous argument 'upstream/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

This is after I git fetch upstream master

Comment: @sureshvv could you make that a new question with details about your repo config?

Comment: @VonC: I meant to say git reset --hard upstream/master.

Comment: @sureshvv ok: can you make a separate question, with a bit more details?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you hadn't fetch that commit yet. So, first do:

```
git fetch origin
```

And then:

```
git checkout --track origin/iss53
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW for other people with the same error message: when this happened to me, the underlying problem was that I was trying to make a branch with spaces in the name. For the set of pre-canned GIT commands I had, branches with spaces were a problem.

(ObDisclaimer: I am very, very far from a git expert. I just know that I had a problem with an identical error message, and the solution was different than the accepted answer)