# adding a git submodule that tracks master

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm using git 1.8.4 and trying to add a submodule that tracks master of another repository. I tried adding it as follows:

```
git submodule add -b master /path/to/myrepo.git
```

And I get the following error when I try to add it

```
Cloning into 'myrepo.git'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'master' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/master' which can not be resolved as commit?
Unable to checkout submodule 'myrepo'
```

I'm not sure what this means...can someone explain?

Comment: Can you try to go within that submodule, do a `git checkout -b master origin/master`, go back one level, and `git submodule update --remote --init`?

Comment: I get the same message message saying the following when I try the first checkout command fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'master' at the same time. Did you intend to checkout 'origin/master' which can not be resolved as commit?

Comment: Then try, in the submodule: `git branch -b master ; git reset --hard origin/master` (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17137740/6309). but if it still complains about `origin/master`, then the remote for that submodule might no be correct. What `git remote -v` returns? Is there a master branch in the actual repo `/path/to/myrepo.git`?

Comment: I verified the actual repo has a master branch. When I run `git remote -v` in the submodule directory I get `origin /path/to/sub/module.git/ (fetch)`
`origin /path/to/sub/module.git/ (push)`
but still getting the same errors about origin master

Comment: What `git branch -avvv` return (in the submodule)? Do you see an `origin/master` in the list of branches?

Comment: If I go into the submodule folder from within the parent project and run that command,I do not. If I checkout the submodule to its own project, then I do.

Comment: Ok. ONe way to move forward would be to start from a fresh clone of the parent repo (without any reference to your submodule), and repeat the steps: `git submodule add -b master /path/to/myrepo.git ; git submodule update --remote --init`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll give that a try. Probably won't be able to get to it for a little bit, but I'll post back with the results. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @VonC Sorry it's taken me so long to get back to you. You were correct that something was messed up with my repository configuration. All works now. If you post your suggestions as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the submodule doesn't appear to have a branch (ie: "`cd submodule ; git branch -avvv`" doesn't return anything, means the submodule configuration in the parent repo isn't properly initialized and updated.

I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895661/adding-a-git-submodule-that-tracks-master?noredirect=1#comment28084156_18895661):

> One way to move forward would be to start from a fresh clone of the parent repo (without any reference to your submodule), and repeat the steps:

```
git submodule add -b master /path/to/myrepo.git ; 
git submodule update --remote --init. –
```