# Pull All the Remote Branch to your fork

Tags: git, github, git-fork

So, I cloned one repository to my fork a few months ago. Now, that repo has some new branches which I want in my fork. What should I do? Please help me.

I am giving the example below for a better understanding.

Say I have repo "upstream/facebook" and I have forked it. After few months when I open "upstream/facebook" it shows below branches:

master
stage_demo
stage_test
stage_help
stage_2020
stage_2021
stage_2019

Branches in my fork:
master
stage_help
stage_2020
stage_2021
stage_2019

So branches stage_demo and stage_test were added which I want in my fork. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fetch them from the upstream and push them to the fork.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731197/7976758 — ` git fetch upstream && git push --all origin`. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+upstream+branches+fork

Answer (score 2):

There is an asymmetry between `git fetch` and `git push` here that is tripping you up.  (The GitHub fork aspect of this is not really relevant: you'd get the same thing with any ordinary set of clones.)

What you'll want to do is simple enough:

1. Run `git fetch` against the repository that has the various branch names.  This results in one *remote-tracking* name, in your own personal repository, for each *branch* name in the repository you're fetching from.

   In your case, you're calling this repository `upstream`, so you would run `git fetch upstream`.  This will create or update the various `upstream/*` names.      You may wish to use `git fetch --prune` here, in case they've *deleted* some branch names, so that your own Git will delete the corresponding remote-tracking names: e.g., if they (`upstream`) used to have a branch named `gronk`, and they no longer have a branch named `gronk`, but your Git created `upstream/gronk` yesterday when they *did* have their `gronk`, this `git fetch --prune upstream` will remove `upstream/gronk`.

   (You can, if you prefer—as I do—just set `fetch.prune` in your personal global Git configuration, so that all `git fetch` operations act as if you had used `git fetch --prune`.  This saves typing it in each time.)
2. For each *remote-tracking name* that now appears in your own repository for which you want a *branch* name to appear in your GitHub fork, use `git push` to create that branch name in your GitHub fork, pointing to the same commit that is now found by that remote-tracking name in your local repository.

   For instance, you now see `upstream/stage_demo` in your repository (locally on your computer).  This is a *remote-tracking name*.  It was created in step 1 above.  You wish to see the branch name `stage_demo` in your GitHub fork.  You just need to ask GitHub to use their Git to set your GitHub fork's `stage_demo` name—this will be a new branch name for them—based on your own `upstream/stage_demo` name.

   To be fully explicit, nailing everything down so that nothing can go wrong, you would need:

   ```
   git push origin refs/remotes/upstream/stage_demo:refs/heads/stage_demo
   ```

   (assuming you call your GitHub repository `origin`).  However, you can almost certainly get away with the slightly shorter:

   ```
   git push origin upstream/stage_demo:refs/heads/stage_demo
   ```

Note that this *does not* create a *local* branch named `stage_demo`.  If you wish to do that, you can do that instead of step 2 above with a simple:

```
git checkout stage_demo
```

or:

```
git checkout -t upstream/stage_demo
```

(or the equivalents with `git switch`, in Git 2.23 or later).  Once you've done that, you can use the simpler:

```
git push origin stage_demo
```

to have your Git send the commits to your GitHub fork and request that GitHub create this branch name in your GitHub fork.

#### More about this asymmetry

What's going on here is simple enough.  Both `git fetch` and `git push` work by having your Git call up some other Git.  Your Git reads from (`git push`) or writes to (`git fetch`) your Git repository; the data transfer direction here is determined by which command you ran.  The asymmetry is that, having gotten or sent some set of commits (possibly empty), the transfer *finishes* by:

- `git fetch`: creating or updating *remote-tracking names* in *your* repository;
- `git push`: creating or updating *branch* names in *their* repository.

The remote-tracking names are the names that look like `origin/master` and `upstream/stage_demo`.  They are built out of two pieces: a *remote*, in this case either `origin` or `upstream`, and a *branch name*, in this case either `master` or `stage_demo`.  The remote is the one you gave to your `git fetch`.  The branch name is the one found in *their* Git.

Your `git fetch` *does not* write on *your* branch names.  That's because your branch names are *yours*.  They find the commits *you* care about.  Their branch names find the commits *they* care about.  You and they only care about the same commits *if and when* you decide that this is the case.  At other times, you and they care specifically about *different* commits, and your Git should not forget your commits in favor of theirs just because you picked up their commits.  This is especially important when you have made *new* commits: they won't remember them, so if your Git updated your *branch* names, your Git would *forget your new commits*.  This would be, well, Very Bad.

But `git push` doesn't create or update any sort of "push-tracking names".  (Perhaps it should—or should be able to—given the way we use GitHub, but it doesn't, because they just don't exist.)  The push creates or updates their *branch* names.  This implies that *they can't create new commits*—which in many cases is *true* because you're pushing to your fork, not to your upstream.  Nobody but *you* can make new commits in your fork, and you normally do that by making them locally, then sending them with `git push`.

When you are merely using your own GitHub fork as a second / backup storage system for your own commits made in your own repo on your own computer, this all works fine.  But here, you're using your own GitHub fork to store your commits *and* to store *their* commits from what you're calling your upstream.  So now you have to do this triangular workflow:

- get their commits from your upstream to your computer; then
- send their commits that are now on your computer to your GitHub repo

and this requires a two-or-more-step dance.

#### There is a case that lacks this asymmetry

If you don't like all of this, there is a way around it.  Git has something called a *mirror clone*.  A mirror clone doesn't use remote-tracking names.  When you run `git fetch` on such a clone, that updates the clone's *branch* names, so that the clone acts as a mirror of some other clone.

The problem with this is that a mirror clone *can't* receive new work by any mechanism other than just getting it from the place you cloned it.  That's because, having hitched all its own branch names to the other repository, any new commits you stick in it will be lost right away by any `git fetch` *unless* those new commits are already in the clone from which you're fetching.  So any new commits you make, you must first send directly to `origin`, before bringing them back into the mirror clone.

Mirror clones, in other words, are not much good here.  They're mainly useful to act as local caches.  Suppose, for instance, your company has offices in London, New York, San Francisco, and Singapore.  Each location has a hundred or more workers who will clone and fetch and merge and so on: a lot of reading.  Instead of everyone fetching directly from London every time, you can have mirror clones in NY, SF, and Singapore, update the mirror clones every 15 minutes, and have each office fetch from the local mirror, which is never any more than 15 minutes out of date.